# Trying to get subset but showing error : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r

I tried to find the subset but it's showing error as :

[image]

I am performing Data Envelopment Analysis using Benchmarking Package in R.
    Although I saw similar Question were asked before but it didn't help me .

Update :Structure and Summary of Database

[image]

I am performing DEA for V6 and V7.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `class(e_crs)`?

Comment: Still not working showing same problem as before : 'Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double''

Comment: It is better to show some reproducible example rather than posting an image.

Comment: class(e_crs)  **output: "Farrell"**

Comment: @RHertel Not working , any other way .

Comment: @akrun's answer should work. I installed the `Benchmarking` package. The data is stored in `e_crs$eff` in this type of object. So `subset(Large.Cap$V1, e_crs$eff > 0.85)` should be ok; or the equivalent version posted in the answer by @akrun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need

```
Large.Cap$V1[e_crs$eff > 0.85]
```

Using a reproducible example from `?dea`

```
library(Benchmarking)
x <- matrix(c(100,200,300,500,100,200,600),ncol=1)
y <- matrix(c(75,100,300,400,25,50,400),ncol=1)
Large.Cap <- data.frame(v1= LETTERS[1:7], v2= 1:7)
e_crs <- dea(x, y, RTS='crs', ORIENTATION='in')
e_crs
#[1] 0.7500 0.5000 1.0000 0.8000 0.2500 0.2500 0.6667
```

The `e_crs` object is a `list`

```
str(e_crs)
#List of 12
# $ eff        : num [1:7] 0.75 0.5 1 0.8 0.25 ...
# $ lambda     : num [1:7, 1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : NULL
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" ...
# $ objval     : num [1:7] 0.75 0.5 1 0.8 0.25 ...
# $ RTS        : chr "crs"
# $ primal     : NULL
# $ dual       : NULL
# $ ux         : NULL
# $ vy         : NULL
# $ gamma      :function (x)  
# $ ORIENTATION: chr "in"
# $ TRANSPOSE  : logi FALSE
# $ param      : NULL
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "Farrell"
```

We extract the 'eff' `list` element from 'e_crs' to `subset` the 'v1' column in 'Large.Cap' dataset.

```
droplevels(Large.Cap$v1[e_crs$eff > 0.85])
#[1] C
#Levels: C
```

Comment: It worked great, but I tried with Farrell efficiency, It was not working. Where did I went wrong.

Comment: @HassanQamar What is Farrel efficiency?  Sorry, I am ignorant about the subject.

Comment: @akrun Your updated answer is crystal clear, Never mind Farrell .Much appreciated.